# How to disable Divider in JsplitPane from hiding one component?

Tags: java, swing, divider, jsplitpane

I have a jsplitPane and 2 component. I want to not let the user click the divider to maximize the top component.
Here is my code.

```
 import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;

public class MovingJSplitPaneDivider {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        JFrame horizontalFrame = new JFrame();
        horizontalFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JComponent topButton = new JButton("Left");
        JComponent bottomButton = new JButton("Right");
        final JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);

        splitPane.setTopComponent(topButton);
        splitPane.setBottomComponent(bottomButton);

        horizontalFrame.add(splitPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        horizontalFrame.setSize(150, 150);
        horizontalFrame.setVisible(true);

        splitPane.setDividerLocation(0.5);
    }
}
```

What I want exactly is that to block the user when he wants to move down the divider.

Comment: See [How to Use Split Panes: Positioning the Divider and Restricting Its Range](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html#divider)

Comment: *"I have a jsplitPane and 2 component.I want to not let the user click the divider to maximize the top component."*  Since both components will always be visible (at least at their minimum size) no matter what we do, why bother trying to override the default behavior of the divider?  If you want to give all extra space to one component, set it to the `CENTER` of a `BorderLayout`..  Calling `horizontalFrame.pack(); horizontalFrame.setMinimumSize(horizontalFrame.getSize());` is also useful at times like this.

Comment: I want to disable the arrow button when the user click to maximize the top component.

Comment: *"I want.."*  ***Why?***

Comment: Unfortunately it's a client requirement :(

Comment: Is the purpose to have an unmovable divider? In that case you can simply set it disabled: `splitPane.setEnabled(false)`. If the intent is to make it respect maximum sizes, then there's no direct support for that. The easiest is to have a listener that resets the divider back if moved outside the allowed boundaries, but that unfortunately does not look particularly pleasing visually. The only way I have found to have maximum size support without any visual glitches is using a custom `SplitPaneUI`.